# User Defined Variables for Cutsom HTML GTM Tags

Tags: html, google-tag-manager

I am trying to pull sales value from the data layer using a custom HTML tag. At the moment, I am using a pre-existing user defined variable that works on the client's Google Ads and Meta Ads tags, however the information is not being pulled into the platform. Their support team has let me know that the Code is setup properly, and the issue lies with the custom variable. I have never set up a  user defined variable for a custom HTML code before.

I have tried inserting the variable into the code. It currently reads like this:

`pagename: encodeURIComponent('Purchase Confirmation'), order : {  sales: {{DLV - value}} }`

1. Is this code snippet correct?
2. If it is, how do I build a new custom variable to pull value from the data layer? I know that the one there works already, I just can't see why it isn't being pulled into the platform.